# What might be a clean Rubyist way of checking an array's contents against partially known values?

Tags: regex, ruby, include, pattern-matching

I have a 3d array, which I need to check the 2nd 'dimension' of against a partially known value. Illustration of array composition below:

```
a = [[[1,1], nil]], [[2,3], [4,8]], [[6,1],[9,9]], [[5,7], nil]]]
```

I need to check this array for presence of an array containing two values, the first of which I'll know the exact contents of, but the second of which all I know is that it'll either be `nil` or a 2 element array with unknown single digit values. In pseudo code what I'm trying to do is; `a.include?([[1,1],*unknown*])`.

Maybe regular expression matcher is the way to go here (?). Perhaps something like;

`a.include?([[1,1],/\[\d,\d\]||(nil)])` (I'm trying to say either; [any single 0-9 digit, any single 0-9 digit] or 'nil')

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is where `group_by` might come in handy, it can help "group" together those with similar characteristics in a quick look-up table. `include?` takes a concrete argument and compares with `==`, so you can't have regex-like placeholders, but you could do something roughly like that with `find` or `any?` using a block to describe the match conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>While "Find Pattern" is still experimental</s> Your use case is perfect for [Pattern matching](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html)

For Example:

```
arr = [[[1,1], nil], [[2,3], [4,8]], [[6,1], [9,9]],
       [[2,3], [3,7]], [[5,7], nil],[[7,9],[42,1]]]

def matches_known_pattern?(arr,known)  
  arr in [*,[^known,nil|[0..9,0..9]],*]
end 

matches_known_pattern?(arr,[1,1]) #=> true
matches_known_pattern?(arr,[2,3]) #=> true 
matches_known_pattern?(arr,[7,8]) #=> false
matches_known_pattern?(arr,[7,9]) #=> false because 42 does not match 0..9
matches_known_pattern?(arr,[1,'a']) #=> false
```

The pattern is fairly self explanatory but it breaks down as `a[0] == known` and `a[1] == nil` or `a[1]` is an array of any 2 <s>Integers</s> Numerics (Including `Integer`, `Float`, etc.) between 0 and 9. If you want to allow any Integer you can replace `[0..9,0..9]` with `[Integer,Integer]`. If you don't care at all what `a[1]` is then you can use `*` (which comes reasonably close to your proposed pattern of `[[1,1],*unknown*]`)

The `[*,...,*]` on either side is the "find pattern" part <s>that is experimental</s>. Essentially it just means find this pattern anywhere in `arr` (first match wins).

One other note is `^known` because pattern matching allows for variable binding without the caret (`^`) the variable `known` would be assigned the value of  the first element (`a[0][0]`) in the pattern. The `^` "pins" the local variable `known` or as described in the docs *"For this case, the pin operator `^` can be used, to tell Ruby 'just use this value as part of the pattern'"*

<sub>Thank you [@steenslag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290394/steenslag) for pointing out that Find Pattern is no longer experimental</sub>

**UPDATE**
To cover the case [@CarySwoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) pointed out (`[[8,8],[1,4.6]]`) this would need to be changed to:

```
case arr 
in [*,[^known,[Integer=>a,Integer=>b]],*]
    (0..9).cover?(a) && (0..9).cover?(b)
in [*,[^known,nil],*]
    true
else 
    false 
end
```

Where the `Integer` and `nil` checks are separated because variable binding is not available for alternate expressions (separated with `|`)

Comment: That’s very cool.

Comment: [Find pattern is no longer experimental](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18585)

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky, nice looking method, which solves exactly my problem and now has me down a fun rabbit hole of learning about Pattern Matching. I really wish I could accept two answers because this works just as well as CarySwoveland's answer, with your nice explanatory description and an arguably tidier looking method. However there was so little between it that I decided to accept the answer that got there first, Cary's. Next time I post and it gets comparable answers the favour will be yours. Thank you again, nice, and helpful .

Comment: FYI: you can use `<expression> in <pattern>` (without "case") to get a boolean result right away.

Comment: @engineersmnky, following some helpful answer awarding criteria hints from Cary I hereby bestow your fine contribution with the one and only green tick allowed under this post.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about repl.it being at Ruby 3.1.2. I normally use Jupyter Playbook, but it's stuck at Ruby 2.7.1. I like repl.it and should use it more.

Answer (score 7):

As I understand the question is as follows, "given an array containing two-element arrays, determine if at least one of its elements is such that its first element equals a given two-element array and its second element equals either nil or an array comprised of two single-digit natural numbers".

You could use the following method to determine if a given array has that property.

```
def is_it_there?(arr, first_known)
  arr.any? do |first,second|
    first == first_known &&
    (second.nil? ||
      (second.is_a?(Array) &&
       second.size == 2 && 
       second.all?(Integer) &&
       second.all?(0..9)
      )
    )
  end
end
```

```
arr = [[[1,1], nil], [[2,3], [4,8]], [[6,1], 0..9], [[5,7], nil],
       [[3,8], 2], [[7,6], [1,2,3]], [[3,1], [1,12]],
       [[2,2], [-1,2]], [[0,1], [3,4.5]]]
```

```
is_it_there?(arr, [2,3]) #=> true
is_it_there?(arr, [1,1]) #=> true
is_it_there?(arr, [5,7]) #=> true
```

```
is_it_there?(arr, [1,6]) #=> false
is_it_there?(arr, [3,8]) #=> false
is_it_there?(arr, [7,6]) #=> false
is_it_there?(arr, [3,1]) #=> false
is_it_there?(arr, [2,2]) #=> false
is_it_there?(arr, [6,1]) #=> false
is_it_there?(arr, [0,1]) #=> false
```

See the version of [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) that takes a pattern as as argument. (Other `Enumerable` methods that take a pattern as an argument are [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F), [Enumerable#one?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F) and [Enumerable#none?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F)).

Comment: `second.all?(0..9)` should work as well.

Comment: @Stefan, I was never aware of that form of `any?` (and `all?`, `one?` and `none?`), and it certainly is a useful one. Have you committed Ruby docs to memory?

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, very helpful and exactly what I was after. To be honest accepting between yours and engineersmnky's answers, which both solved my problem nicely, was a difficult decision and came down to me accepting this one because you got there first. To amateur dev eyes I can read yours a bit easier, but engineersmnky's method just looks a tad cleaner doesn't it. Thanks again.

Comment: jbk, personally, I would not consider time of posting when selecting an answer. While askers are encouraged to select the answer they find most helpful, often one will see the green checkmark going to the most innovative answer, even when it seems the asker may opt for a more straightforward solution in practice. I am all for that because it draws attention to the solution that has the greatest educational value for readers as a whole. While there is something to be learn from my answer (as evidenced by the the fact that I learned something from @Stefan's comment),...

Comment: ...@engineersmnky’s answer is the most innovative and arguably, the most interesting one here. You can guess which answer I would select.

Comment: Answer awarding criteria suggestions noted @CarySwoveland, therefore award re-awarded!